# Write element multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a page to interact with multiple camera's at the same time. Because of that I have a page with basically 1 set of control's that call on a JavaScript that repeat an X number of time's where only the name and 1 variable changes. Is there a way to read the document and write it an X number of times and replace only those value's in each pass? I know how to do it in PHP but i would like to be able to do it client side.

So basically you have:

```
<div name="camera1" style="left:100px">
<input type="button" onclick="setFps(1)">
</div>
```

Where the 100px and the 1 need to be changed every pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    document.write('<div name="camera'+i+'" style="left:100px;"><input type="button" onclick="setFps(1)"></div>');
</script>
```

but, unless you have a good reason to do this, i would not recommend doing it like this.
it's just the easiest way to do it and given the fact that this is your only post and it is just 1 simple google-search away, this'll do.

Comment: I found this method, but this is a very simpel version of what I'am actually making. The reason to do it like that is because if i change something in the first camera set, i want it to change in the rest of the cameraset's as well. So lets say I add a button, i don't want to add them 10 time's.

Comment: but you can easily do the same thing on the server side. just run a loop there... no need to do this on the client side

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
---HTML---
<div id="cameraDisplay">
    <script>displayCameras()</script>
</div>

---Javascript---
function displayCameras()
{
    var parent = document.getElementById("cameraDisplay");
    parent.innerHTML = ""; //Clear parent before adding cameras

    var fpsValues = [1, 2, 3, ...]; //Array of all the FPS integers
    var leftValues = [100, 200, 300, ...]; //Array of all the left stylings

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
    {
        var camera = document.createElement("div");
        camera.setAttribute("name", "camera" + i.toString());
        camera.style.left = leftValues[i].toString + "px";

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "button";
        (function() { //Create an anonymous function to store correct value of i - otherwise mutable errors occur
            var fps = i;
            input.onclick = function() {setFps(fpsValues[fps]);};
        })();

        camera.apendChild(input);
        parent.appendChild(camera);
    }
}
```